# Having trouble putting label on 1 line and input and a select together on the next line

Tags: html, css, alignment

Kinda stuck on this problem.  I can easily put labels and inputs on the same line if desired, or on separate lines when needed... but, so far trying to accomplish a label on 1 line, and the input and select together has been a futile task.

So, what I tried...   I tried making the label a block element, and the input and select both inline-blocks.  You can see my 2 commented out CSS rules for what I was trying.  I tried label as width 100% and other things.

It either does all 3 on 1 line, or all 3 as blocks.  I have a feeling it's because the label is wrapped around them but that shouldn't matter since I can manipulate the label and input easily but when it comes to label, input, select it doesn't want to work...

A hacky ugly method I was thinking of would be to absolute position the select but I was hoping for a more proper way to do it. (not sure if that would even work).  I prefer a clean solution whenever possible and absolute positioning this seems a poor way to try to fix it.  There may be something easy I am overlooking...  which is why I am here.  :)

Any ideas?  (I don't really care about older browsers either)

What I am looking for is... (as per the fiddle)

...
City (this is a label and sits up here)
(input under the label)

Phone Number (the label up here)
(input here)(select here)
...

```css
.form-outer-container,
.primary-button {
  font-size: 1.025em;
}

.form-outer-container {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 3px 0 0 0;
  padding: 2px 2px;
}

li > label {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

li > label > input,
li > label > textarea {
  display: block;
}

li > label > input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
textarea {
  color: #0a290a;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

.label-input-select-combo > input,
.label-input-select-combo > select {
  /* display: inline-block; */
}

.label-input-select-combo {
  /* display: block !important; */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>Address
      <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>City
      <input type="text" data-bind="city" placeholder="Oshawa" tabindex="3">
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>Country
      <input type="text" data-bind="country" placeholder="Canada" tabindex="5">
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="editor sub-editor" data-rest-path="/api/actphone" data-parent-id="cid">
    <label class="label-input-select-combo">Phone number
      <input type="text" data-bind="phone" placeholder="905-999-3590" tabindex="6">
      <select data-bind="type">
        <option value="M">Mobile</option>
        <option value="W" selected>Work</option>
        <option value="H">Home</option>
        <option value="O">Other</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="primary-button editor-save">Create</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible options:

1. Wrap the phone number input and select dropdown in a `<span>` and give the `<span>` a `display: flex;`
2. Add a `<br/>` tag after the label text, then give the `input` a `display: inline-block;`

Like this:

```css
.form-outer-container,
.primary-button {
  font-size: 1.025em;
}

.form-outer-container {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 3px 0 0 0;
  padding: 2px 2px;
}

li > label {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

li > label > input,
li > label > textarea {
  display: block;
}

li > label > input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
textarea {
  color: #0a290a;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

.input-block {
  display: flex;
}

.input--left {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>Address
      <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>City
      <input type="text" data-bind="city" placeholder="Oshawa" tabindex="3">
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>Country
      <input type="text" data-bind="country" placeholder="Canada" tabindex="5">
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="editor sub-editor" data-rest-path="/api/actphone" data-parent-id="cid">
    <label>Phone number
      <span class="input-block">
      <input type="text" data-bind="phone" placeholder="905-999-3590" tabindex="6">
      <select data-bind="type">
        <option value="M">Mobile</option>
        <option value="W" selected>Work</option>
        <option value="H">Home</option>
        <option value="O">Other</option>
      </select>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="editor sub-editor" data-rest-path="/api/actphone" data-parent-id="cid">
    <label class="label-input-select-combo">Phone number<br/>
      <input type="text" class="input--left" data-bind="phone" placeholder="905-999-3590" tabindex="6">
      <select data-bind="type">
        <option value="M">Mobile</option>
        <option value="W" selected>Work</option>
        <option value="H">Home</option>
        <option value="O">Other</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="primary-button editor-save">Create</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'll give that a try...  (also, thank you for formatting the code... I thought I did it right... I must have done something wrong when I hit CTRL+K to indent the code).

Comment: You correctly added formatted code. The other option is to add a code snippet - https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Ah, thank you!   I'll look for that option next time!   It looks nicer your way!  :)  Also, your solution works better than the other solution.  While they both work, keeping the label wrapped around both is preferable.   I also like how Flex lines them up.  Thank you for your time!  Much appreciated!

Comment: I do find it interesting that I can put label and input on separate lines quite easily, but adding the select inside the label (along with the input) seems to cause it to behave differently.  Without the select in there... it's easy to manipulate just the label, and just the input.  I was hoping all 3 could be manipulated.  I am totally happy with Flex as on the really complicated forms I am using grid... so, flex doesn't bother me.  Support is quite wide.  Also, it appears div's aren't allowed inside UL/LI from the MDN docs which makes sense so the div option others posted is invalid unless

Comment: I move the label.

Answer (score 0):

The input is full width. You need to set it to inline-block. This will put it on the same line and what's before it and what's after it. Put `<br />` after "Phone number" or put a div around "Phone number" so it's not on the same line at the input.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping all in tag label. tag label is only for description. You need to change by this:

```
<label class="label-input-select-combo">Phone number</label>
<input type="text" data-bind="phone" placeholder="905-999-3590" tabindex="6">
<select data-bind="type">
  <option value="M">Mobile</option>
  <option value="W" selected>Work</option>
  <option value="H">Home</option>
  <option value="O">Other</option>
</select>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h716npLs/1/)

Comment: Thank you.  That does work.  I didn't try that because I was able to put Label and Inputs on their own lines even with label wrapped around both.  I guess wrapping label around 2 elements causes it to behave differently.  Interesting....  do you know why it doesn't work wrapped around both input and select? when it does work wrapped around just input?  The MDN specs say select is allowed inside label (also input).  It doesn't mention both together however...

Comment: When you wrap the label around the input it allows a wider range of clicking to initiate input.  Your answer does work, but the Flex option posted is closer to what I was looking for and allows me to keep the label wrapped around the input and select.   Thank you for your time in responding.  Much appreciated.